# Animations in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, animation

I'm new to animations in react and would like to animate a simple posts app.

I would like to loop through all posts and render 3 posts at a time where the oldest post is removed from the view, a new one is inserted on top of the remaining posts.
Something like this -
[image]

I'm not sure which library I should be using in order to implement this.

My code so far is very simple -

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import title from "./assets/title.png";
import posts from "./posts";
import Post from "./post";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <img src={title} alt="title" className="img" />
        {posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <Post key={post.id} post={post}/>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'd appreciate help

Comment: Take a look at framer. https://www.framer.com/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments already mentioned, Framer Motion makes things like this really easy.

I created a small example in Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-glitter-732dc?file=/src/App.js

In the example I used motion.div elements around the Posts:

```
      <motion.div
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{
          opacity: 1,
          transition: { type: "tween", delay: 1, duration: 1 }
        }}
        transition={{ type: "tween", duration: 1 }}
        layout
        key={post.id}
      >
        <Post background={post.color} />
      </motion.div>
```

The initial and animate property will create the fade effect when a new post enters. The "layout" prop will cause that the old elements that remain smoothly shift to their new positions.